# What Javascript game engines are out there, other than Impact?

Tags: javascript, html5, editors

Does anybody know of a decent (*meaning* preferably free `;)`) alternative to [Impact](http://impactjs.com/)? Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: I *almost* flagged this as off-topic because it's a "which library" question that is turning into a list.  Perhaps you should add some more specifics or make it CW?  It's a good question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good jquery/javascript game engines?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16014/what-are-some-good-jquery-javascript-game-engines)

Comment: @bummzack: I don't really think so... I'm thinking in terms of a complete IDE, with graphical editor, code snippets, etc.

Comment: @CountZero Well, then you should specifically mention that in your question. Also the answers given don't seem to address that and are pretty much the same as the ones in the duplicate question.

Comment: "which tech to use" or "what is a list of things that do X" are off topic.  See the [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few here's a list of some:

[Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/) (open source)

[MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org/index.html) (open source)

[LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/) (open source)

These are all free, and seem fairly finished. I don't know much about the Lime and Melon, but Crafty has a decent community where you can get help in their forums. Which you choose depends on what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lengthy list: https://gist.github.com/768272/. 
Here's something I'm making: https://github.com/Yannbane/Irenic.

Comment: Irenic: "Current state: being recoded from scratch as an Entity System, unusable."
Bane, why post it if it's not ready for use?

Comment: Well, actually it's quite usable, I tend to commit stable builds to GitHub only, I just forgot to change the state since it *actually* became usable. Although, it does not provide a lot features yet, only essential stuff... Also, I see nothing wrong in letting people know about ongoing projects. I did say that I was *working* on it.

Comment: Ok, then I see, thought it was still unusable. Then I don't see the problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Playin](http://code.google.com/p/playn/) looks pretty good. It's free and open-source game library from Google. It was used for conversion of Angry Birds to Chrome browser. Games written in *playin* should run both in Chrome and Android phones.